# E: Unable to locate package on Rasbian Buster

Tags: raspbian-buster, packages

I am new to working on Raspberry pi. Currently I am working on Raspberry pi 4 and have installed Raspbian Buster on it.
I am trying to install few things but i am always getting this message
E: Unable to locate Packages of libgazebo9
and similar message for different packages.

Comment: Can you please copy / paste the command you are using and its output.  I'm a little baffled by the 'E:' in your question - that infers a Windows operating system rather than Linux.

Comment: @Andyroo The 'E' is a normal error indicator with apt on Pi OS / Debian. OP is trying to install packages that are not in the repo. As you mention full command and error messages should be posted

Comment: In addition to the commands you used, please [edit](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/posts/119359/edit) your question and add the output of these commands to it: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` and `ping -c3 raspbian.raspberrypi.org`.

Comment: @Dirk - Thanks for the note I had never noticed it but must have as I had errors with Apt :-). Old systems die hard...

Comment: simple problem ... `libgazebo9` is not available on the pi - as it is only available on amd64/i386 architectures - https://packages.debian.org/buster/libgazebo9 - what are you trying to install